# Simple validation javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function:

```
if (myform.telephone.value.length < 10){
jAlert ('Please enter at least 10 characters!',function(){$(myform.telephone).focus();});
return false;
```

If the user enters less than 10 characters, an alert is triggered. I need to modify the script so that the alert pops if the user enters less than 10 DIGITS (0,1,2,etc)..

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: As the OP correctly pointed out, there was a bug in the previous method. I advise not to use `isNan` as it is broken. I've updated the answer, code below.

This can be easily done by mathcing the input against a regular expression and then checking if the resulting number has 10 or more digits. Like:

```
var validate = function(){
    var number = tryParseNumber(input.value);
    if(number.toString().length < 10){
        alert("Invalid input");
    } else {
        alert("Valid output: " + number);
    }
};

var tryParseNumber = function (value) {
  if(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/.test(value))
    return Number(value);
  return false;
}
```

[See this Fiddle for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BG4du/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)  
{  
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
  if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))  
        {  
      return true;  
        }  
      else  
        {  
        alert("message");  
        return false;  
        }  
}
```

To valid a phone number like
XXX-XXX-XXXX
XXX.XXX.XXXX
XXX XXX XXXX

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)  
{  
  var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;  
  if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))  
        {  
      return true;  
        }  
      else  
        {  
        alert("message");  
        return false;  
        }  
}
```

If you want to use a + sign before the number in the following way
+XX-XXXX-XXXX
+XX.XXXX.XXXX
+XX XXXX XXXX
use the following cod

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)
{
  var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
        {
      return true;
        }
      else
        {
        alert("message");
        return false;
        }
}
```